# LINQ query that given some As each one with some Bs returns all (ab) pairs

Tags: c#, linq

I have some containers that have some properties and contains some items.

```
public class AnimalDomain
{
    public string Domain {get; set;}
    
    List<Animal> Animals {get; set;}
}

public class Animal
{ 
     public string Name {get; set;}

}
```

What I want to achieve is that given a list of animal's domains each one containing its own animals, each animal is converted into a tuple that has also the properties of its own domain.

In example

```
public class ExtendedAnimal
{
     public string DomainName {get; set;}

     public string AnimalName {get; set;}
}
```

The prototype for the function is

```
 public IEnumerable<ExtendedAnimal> MergeDomainAndAnimal(IEnumerable<AnimalDomain> input)
 { 
       // some LINQ query.
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
IEnumerable<ExtendedAnimal> MergeDomainAndAnimal(IEnumerable<AnimalDomain> input) =>
    from domain in input
    from animal in domain.Animals
    select new ExtendedAnimal
    {
        DomainName = domain.Name,
        AnimalName = animal.Name
    };
```